# Hashmap result only show one row

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap

I use hashmap and store it in jsp page, but I am getting only one row of data in the jsp page

```
 System.out.println("connection established successfully...!!");   
 ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select SEC_NO,FACT_NO from sec where FACT_NO='B07C'");

if (!rs.next() ) {
      request.setAttribute("stts", "0");

}
else {

    HashMap<String, String> arrList = new HashMap<String, String>();
    do
    {
        String SEC_NO = rs.getString("SEC_NO");
        String FACT_NO = rs.getString("FACT_NO");
        arrList.put("sec_no", SEC_NO);
        arrList.put("fact_no", FACT_NO);
        System.out.println("Hasil : " + arrList); 

    }while(rs.next());

        request.setAttribute("datas", arrList);

        request.setAttribute("stts", "1");
    } 


    }
    catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
    }
helper = new ControllerHelper(request, response);
helper.doGet("grafik/grafik.jsp");
```

What is the problem could be?

Comment: <c:forEach items="${datas}" var="pro">
     <a href="#">${pro}</a>
    <br/>
</c:forEach>

This is the sjp page code

Comment: Each time your `do ... while()` loop executes, you **replace** the existing hash map entries with new ones. You are not accumulating all the values.

Comment: So,,
What should the code ?

Answer (score 0):

Like **Jason** said, you add your value in Hashmap with key 
**"sec_no"** and **"fact_no"** each iteration.

You have 3 variants, as I see.
1 - add your **SEC_NO** and **FACT_NO** with different keys like

```
HashMap<String, String> arrList = new HashMap<String, String>();
int i=0;
int j=0;
do
{
    String SEC_NO = rs.getString("SEC_NO");
    String FACT_NO = rs.getString("FACT_NO");
    arrList.put(i, SEC_NO);
    arrList.put(j, FACT_NO);
    System.out.println("Hasil : " + arrList); 
    j=i+1;
    i=i+2;
}while(rs.next());
```

2 - it is to use MultiValueMap, where you can add your multi-value on 1 key.

3 - Add your value from each iteration, into List, for example, and after all iterations, you will be able to make

```
HashMap<String, List> arrList = new HashMap<String, List>();
arrList.put("sec_no", list1);
arrList.put("fact_no", list2);
```

where list1 and list2 have already values

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `HashMap` key through loop:

```
HashMap<String, String> arrList = new HashMap<String, String>();
                do
                {
                    String SEC_NO = rs.getString("SEC_NO");
                    String FACT_NO = rs.getString("FACT_NO");
                    arrList.put("sec_no", SEC_NO); //Overwriting
                    arrList.put("fact_no", FACT_NO); //Overwriting
                    System.out.println("Hasil : " + arrList); 
                }while(rs.next());
```

Because of that you have only two key in your `HashMap` all the time.

its better to have unique key value for your `HashMap` like this:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> arrList = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
                    int i=0;
                    int j=1;
                    do
                    {
                        String SEC_NO = rs.getString("SEC_NO");
                        String FACT_NO = rs.getString("FACT_NO");
                        arrList.put(i, SEC_NO); 
                        arrList.put(j, FACT_NO); 
                        System.out.println("Hasil : " + arrList); 
                        i++;j=i+1;
                    }while(rs.next());
```

Or (i don't exactly which approach you want to use) you can use `STRING,STRING HashMap`:

```
HashMap<String, String> arrList = new HashMap<String, String>();
int i=0;
                    do
                    {
                        String SEC_NO = rs.getString("SEC_NO");
                        String FACT_NO = rs.getString("FACT_NO");
                        arrList.put("sec_no_"+i, SEC_NO); 
                        arrList.put("fact_no_"+i, FACT_NO); 
                        System.out.println("Hasil : " + arrList); 
                    }while(rs.next());
```

Or Used `MultiValueMap`.